# How can I see/change what makes vim beep?

Tags: vim, audio, vimrc

Vim beeps. A lot. For instance, whenever I type a '>' in insert mode (can't even guess why it dislikes that specific character), or execute a macro, or tab-complete a file path. This is really starting to annoy me. Is there anywhere I can see a list of the things that make vim beep, and disable a bunch of them?

Comment: could be a plugin... a related Q&A on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915356/bell-frequently-sounds-when-editing-vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Sundeep's link disables a Vim plug-in. As a last resort, turn off all System Sounds. Try: [How to disable the beep sound system-wide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16762/244243) or as most distros use pulseaudio try: [Mute sound effects on Ubuntu from command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309223/244243)